# Is ASP.NET MVC really only for 5% of Programmers?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, webforms

I've seen this phrase (ASP.NET MVC is for 5% of programmers) thrown around and have wondered if it is actually true?

Since the release of ASP.NET MVC, I have seen more and more questions and tutorials created for MVC while those for WebForms seem to slowly disappear.

Looking over stackoverflow questions, majority are about ASP.NET MVC.

I, for one, adopted MVC a few months (~6 months) ago and haven't looked back since. I think once a person overcomes MVC's initial learning curve, they'll learn how valuable and versatile it is.

Any thoughts on this? Is ASP.NET MVC really for 5% of programmers?

Comment: Dear god, what we need is a 5%er patch. You know, like the 1% patch for biker gangs. That'll show 'em.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds about right to me.  I think you are seeing some selection bias.  The people who are likely to use ASP.NET MVC right now can still be considered early adopters and I think a disproportionate number of Stackoverflow users fall into that category.

So while you are seeing a lot of MVC questions being posted, it is still the tip of the ASP.NET iceberg.

Also, it might be argued that there are already a considerable body of tutorials/questions for ASP.NET asked and answered on the internet which means there are more resources for those who search for their problem.  MVC being the newer technology will therefore generate more questions right now because there is less material out there on how to do certain things.

Answer (score 3):

90% of statistics are made up....

Personally I see MVC as the future - but wouldn't rewrite an application *just* to use MVC.

Comment: "90% of statistics are made up"... Including this one of course ;)

Answer (score 1):

Seems like there's a lot of implications to that statement.  But, I think many programmers are of the opinion "right tool for the right job".  If ASP.NET MVC is that tool, then use it.  If it's not, use something else.

Personally, I believe the MVC pattern is perfect for the web.  But the specific platform and framework can depend wildly on a number of factors.